# Countdown Timer in Android out of sync?

Tags: java, android, calendar, count

I am trying to make a countdown timer. I have came up with this code and initially I thought it worked. However when I run the app two things happen which I don't know how to fix...

1. It is out of sync, although it is the system Time and Date it said there was only 60 days left not 61 when I know it is 61!!
2. If I close the app and go back it resets the counters...

Any help with this would be appreciated, its not for anything particular just a personal project.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView dateBx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
        final TextView minBx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minBx);
        final TextView hourBx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hourBx);

        //set todays date
        DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        //target date
        DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(2012,11,25);
        //set maths
        long time1 = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
        long time2 = cal2.getTimeInMillis();
        //difference variable
        long diff = time2 - time1;
        //equations
        long diffSec = diff / 1000;
        long dMins = diff / (60 * 1000);
        long dHour = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
        long dDay = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

       new CountDownTimer(diff, 1000) 
       {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
             {
                 mTextField.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                 dateBx.setText("Days remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                 minBx.setText("Minutes remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / (60 * 1000));
                 hourBx.setText("hours remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / (60 * 60 * 1000));
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 mTextField.setText("done!");
             }
          }.start();



}
```

My code is a combination of some things that I learnt, in java and android, if you think of a better way of doing it all together then please let me know :)

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example with both dates and times where the day count is wrong?

Comment: the variables i am assigning to text fields are not in sync with the clock, that is the problem i am having with this

Answer (score 1):

Android is not a Real Time OS so you can count that your Timer will run exactly every 1000 ms.

The most practical approach is, for each invocation, get the current date, get the target date, and recalculate the days/hours/minutes/seconds remaining (just as you did as the beginning of your app).

That would also solve your problem when closing/opening your app.

Comment: I have been trying to work out what you mean, and i cannot figure it out, any example you can show? or code you show the layout of where it would go i can work it out from there, besides that i know what you mean i just dont know how to work it out...

Comment: instead of passing `diff` to your timer and substracting `1000` at each invocation, recalculate `diff` (from the beginning) each time. That way your alarm won't lose its synch.

Comment: Hi sorry about this i guess i am being a bit dense!! i dont fully understand what you mean, i have played about with it and i cant seem to grasp what you mean? any chance you could show some examples? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to sync the countDownTimer.

(as "onTick()" is not accurate according to Android)

The trick is to use only "onFinish()" and start a new timer using an Interface.

make a EXTENDED CLASS of countDownTimer:

```
public class oneShotTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    TickListener invokeOnFinish;    // Interface

public oneShotTimer (Context parent, int tickTime, TickListener contextPointer) {
    super(tickTime, tickTime);          // DEBUG: (/60)
....
}
```

At the OnFinish():

```
 public void onFinish() {
     invokeOnFinish.restartTimer();    
 }
 public void onTick() {
     Log.e("Timer", "Not suppose to happen");
 }
```

Define an interface:

```
public interface TickListener {
    public void restartTimer();
}
```

Now at the parent Object do the following:

1) Before starting the timer, get the time in MillinSecond -> "startTime";

2) Create the method for "TickListener::restartTimer" (I wrote psadu code)

```
@Override
public void restartTimer() {
    // check if timer is done (make your own variable to monitor that)

    // get the currentTime in MilliSecond

    // calc TickTime , if we know that 30 tick are already counted 
    // there for ((30+1) x wantedTickTime) give us the target time for the next tick.
    // TickTime = (31 x wantedTickTime) - (currentTime - startTime)  
    // for example, we want 1sec ticks, after 30 ticks it finished at 30.2 sec
    // => (31 x 1) - (40.2 - 10)  = 0.8 is the time we need to re start timer.

    // re-run a new Timer with the new TickTime 
}
```

Now let see how Java garbage collection will handle it.